# Compatibility of motherboard with ram and processor

Tags: compatibility

can you please tell me whether this motherboard Intel DH55PJ will support following processor and RAMs?

```
RAM: HyperX 8GB KIT DDR3 1600MHz CL10 Fury Blue Series
CPU: Intel Core i7-7700
```

At the moment I have

```
CPU: Inter Core i3 550 3.2GHz 
RAM: Kingston 2GB DDR3 1333MHz CL9 (2x)
```

I would like to boost my PC a bit and I hope this would help .. Will those work ok?

Comment: No, definitely not.

Comment: If you are changing (almost) everything, you will get a better result with a new computer.

Comment: can you please recommend some RAM for my motherboard that will help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [intel motherboard](https://ark.intel.com/products/48955/Intel-Desktop-Board-DH55PJ) has an [LGA1156 socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1156). That [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1156) is compatible with an i7, but not the 7th gen, it's only compatible with the 1st gen such as the Lynnfield i7-8xx processors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors#%22Lynnfield%22_(45_nm). However the 1600MHz ram you are talking about should be able to slow down to the 1333 MHz speed that the motherboard supports.

You would be better off saving money by getting a CPU cheaper and <strike>slower</strike> [faster](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-i7-7700-vs-Intel-i5-8400/2905vs3097) than the i7-7700 such as the cheaper Intel Core i5-8400 (8th gen LGA 1151 socket), and purchasing a new motherboard to go with it for a total spend of cheaper than just the i7-7700 by itself.

Comment: thx ... will think about new motherboard :)

Comment: @Mr.P keep in mind, that IF you are using MS Windows, that the license will be tied to the old motherboard unless you have a retail box version of Windows. You might need to go for the i3-8100 8th gen and buy a new license of windows too. It will still be 3 or more times faster than your old system

Comment: thx for reminding me :) I am running on Ubuntu ;-)